# Getting data from service in component in Angular 2

Tags: angular

So I created a component where it handles products.

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.products = [];
   this.products = this.product.all();
}
```

In my services class I am retrieving the products in the constructor and retrieving it through the all method.

```
constructor(private http: Http, private admin: AdminService){
   admin.getProduct(function(response){
     this.products = response.data;
   }.bind(this));
}

all(): any{
   return this.products;
}
```

This issue with this is that the all method is run before the products arrive. Is there anyway I can get the service class to load the products and be able to retrieve the products back in my component?

Comment: Could you be more precise on what you are trying to achieve? On a successful API call., you already replaced the empty array with data, why are you calling the all() function again??

Comment: service should be inject able why have it in constructor ?

Comment: Are you familiar with RxJS, Promises or callbacks? Depending on your answer to this, we may show the easiest path for you. (The root of the problem is because `AdminService#getProduct()` is an **asynchronous** function -- and RxJS, Promises or callbacks are techniques to handle those.)

Comment: Have you added providers??

Comment: @ManiS the constructor of the services reach out to backend to retrieve data. The all method is called when a component needs the data.

Comment: @acdcjunior Yes I am familiar but not sure how that would be achieved.

Comment: Caching might be the solution for you. Please refer to this link and let me know if you still feel difficulty handing it. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rxjs/8247/common-recipes/26490/caching-http-responses#t=201706122223566672299)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion using RxJS:

```
productsChange = new Subject();                   // added this line
constructor(private http: Http, private admin: AdminService){
   admin.getProduct(function(response){
     this.productsChange.next(response.data);     // changed this line
   }.bind(this));
}

all(): Observable<any> {                          // changed the return type
   return this.productsChange;                    // changed this line
}
```

And the component:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.products = [];
   this.product.all().subscribe((products) => {   // changed this line
       this.products = products;                  // added this line
   });                                            // added this line
}
```